# Laravel - select rows from previous week on monday

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp

I have a table **mdl_forum_posts** with a field **created** that's a *BIGINT* (database is not mine, so don't blame for the type of field). An example of value is *1504170577*. The value is saved as a timestamp.

There will run a cron every Monday (first day of the week) that needs to select all the rows created in the previous week (created value in week before).

I'm trying to do this:

```
$currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();

$postsNL = DB::table('mdl_forum_posts')->whereBetween('created', array($agoDate,$currentDate))->get();
```

But this isn't returning any rows (and it should!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you do some operations on a Carbon object it will modify the instance of the object itself, so basically when you run the statement

```
$agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();
```

you are also modifying `$currentDate`.

The below code should do the trick:

```
$currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$agoDate = $currentDate->copy()->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek()->setTime(23, 59, 59);

$postsNL = DB::table('mdl_forum_posts')
      ->whereBetween('created', array($agoDate->timestamp, $currentDate->timestamp))
      ->get();
```

The `copy` method will make all the modifications on a copy of the `Carbon` instance, not affetting the original one.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why should it?  MySQL won't just compare an integer to a date.  The integers are called unix timestamps and you can easily get unix timestamps out of Carbon by using the timestamp property on a Carbon instance:

```
$postsNL = DB::table('mdl_forum_posts')
      ->whereBetween('created', array($agoDate->timestamp, $currentDate->timestamp))
      ->get();
```

Since Carbon extends DateTime, you could also use the [getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method.

Comment: I'm still getting no results back.